# Homotopy of paths on $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\alpha(t) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t), 0)$ and $\beta(t) = (0,0,1)$ be paths from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$. Find a homotopy from $\alpha$ to $\beta$.

I think that the naive idea of taking $$H: [0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{S}^2, (t,s) \mapsto \frac{(1-s)\alpha(t) + s\beta(t)}{\|(1-s)\alpha(t) + s\beta(t)\|}$$ doesn't work here as we can't guarantee that the denominator is non-zero? I'm not familiar with any other approaches in this case. Could we do something to modify the arguments of cosine and sine using $s$? This would of course leave the last coordinate to $0$ which we also want to go to $1$.

Would $$H(t,s)=(\cos(2\pi t)(1-s), \sin(2\pi t)(1-s), s)$$ work?

Comment: I'd suggest thinking about it geometrically first, and then figure out how to write down the formula second. Do you have a good image of what the two paths represent? (Note: thinking of $S^2$ as the Earth is a good way to describe them.)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I think I do. I'm just squishing the circle $S^1$ to the north pole right?

Comment: And where does that $S^1$ sit on the globe?

Comment: Can you help me understand why the naive idea doesn't work here? Intuitively I thought that I could just take lines from $S^1$ to the north pole and they shouldn't go through the origin, but they apparently might? @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: Sorry, I only just noticed your second suggestion. That's close, but it doesn't lie in $S^2$ either. Can you figure out what the correct radius for a circle that is $s$ units above the equator is?

Comment: Man, I responded way too quickly! Are you sure your naive idea doesn't work? You are drawing straight lines (in $\mathbb R^3$) from the north pole to the equator, and projecting back on to the Earth's surface. This should be continuous so long as you stay away from the center of the earth.

Comment: Did you try writing out the denominator explicitly, all three coordinates, and setting them all equal to zero?

Comment: I didn't yet, I was told that it doesn't work... Also the new radius for the shifted circle would be $\sqrt{1-s^2}$ right? $H(t, s) = (\cos(2\pi t) \sqrt{1-s^2}, \sin(2 \pi t) \sqrt{1-s^2}, s)$ could then do the trick? @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: Yup, that radius looks right. But I also think the naive idea would work here too. Maybe whoever told you it wouldn't work was just saying that you can't always assume it will work, and they'd be right. But what it means is that you have to explicitly check it in each new situation. And I'm like 99.99% sure it'd work here

Comment: Also, BTW, even though we both know that you've now got the correct radius, you should supply the explicit computation that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ does equal 1 for all $s$ and $t$. It's like 2-3 lines, but it's the polite thing to do for your readers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your homotopy is absolutely correct because the denominator is always non-zero. In fact we have
$$\phi(t,s) := (1-s)\alpha(t) + s\beta(t) = ((1-s)\cos(2\pi t),(1-s)\sin(2\pi t), s) $$
and therefore
$$\lVert \phi(t,s) \rVert^2  = (1-s)^2\cos^2(2\pi t) + (1-s)^2\sin^2(2\pi t) + s^2 = (1-s)^2 + s^2 = 1 -2s + 2s^2 .$$
But the quadratic equation $2s^2 - 2s +  1 =  0$ does not have real roots.